# Example of browserify implementation with Node.JS, Express, and EJS

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, ejs, parse-server

I'm having trouble getting browserify to work on my web app.

I browserify in the terminal and it creates the bundle.js file. I put it in my public/javascripts folder and included it in my EJS file, but still can't get code to work:

terminal:

```
browserify public/javascripts/chat.js > bundle.js
```

chat.js file:

```
$(function() {
    var parse = require("parse").Parse;
    let query = new Parse.Query('Chat');
    let subscription = query.subscribe();

    subscription.on('open', () => {
        //console.log('subscription opened');
        alert("sub opened");
    });

    subscription.on('create', (object) => {
        //console.log('object created: ' + object.get('message'));
        alert('object created: ' + object.get('message'))
    });
});
```

ejs file:

```
<script src="javascripts/bundle.js "></script>
```

Answer (score 0):

`src="javascripts/bundle.js"` is a **relative path**. when your app comes to this path it will look for a folder named `javascript` within the same folder that your `server.js` (or whatever files which running node process ) is and cannot find it; Cuz i am pretty sure you are not going to serve your back-end app within your public folder.

I think you meant `src="/javascripts/bundle.js"`. Now it is an **absolute path** and if you're serving static files from `public` folder:

```
app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname, 'public')));
```

this file will serve from `http://yourhost/javascripts/bundle.js` regardless of where you `server.js` is positioned or running.

Comment: I'm getting a 200 on the src file, but I'm still unable to access the Parse module from the bundle.js file

Answer (score 0):

UPDATE: Didn't realize this, but I had to include the chat.js script beneath the bundle.js script and got it to work. Thanks @Dnitro

Changed it to:

```
<script src="javascripts/bundle.js "></script>
<script src="javascripts/chat.js "></script>
```